# How can I detect continuous touches/pressed with Unity 4.6's UI elements?

Tags: unity

I've recently switched to Unity 4.6. My previous workflow when creating continuous-input controls (the kind where you measure continuous touch input on a single button) was to create a `GUITexture` and then perform hit-testing on that texture as long as a finger was touching the screen.

With the new GUI there seems to be no way to measure this type of input, as `GUITextures` objects can no longer be created and the new UI types don't support hit testing.

I'm talking about a button that's supposed to act like a car accelerator where, for example, a simple `OnClick()` doesn't work because I need to measure if the button is being pressed continuously rather than it working as an on/off toggle. How can I implement this?

Answer (score 2):

It turns out you *can* implement this using the event system.

The `PointerDown` and `PointerUp` events can be used to track when the start and stop of the continuous touch. I'm currently using them, and they work fine. It's preferred to use events rather than checking on every frame, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Use the EventTrigger component for more events that aren't build-into the button element.